# Tikz-Feynman for a 4-point vertex automatic creation

Tags: tikz-feynman

I'd like to create a Feynman diagram for the λφ⁴ theory that is simply the interaction 4-point vertex.  For some reason, in Ti*k*Z-Feynman it seems to be automatic that the incoming and outgoing lines go up-down and left-right even though no one would ever draw it like that. Short of manually inputting the vertex locations, how can I get this rotated 45 degrees?

(I've seen a similar post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324829), but it seems like that person wanted the lines positioned in a strange way. I'd like them positioned at 90 degrees to each other.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The algorithms that [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](http://jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman) ([CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman)) uses only figure out how to place the vertices relative to other vertices.  Unfortunately, the algorithms have no notion of the overall orientation.

Fortunately, you can easily adjust the orientation with either

```
vertical=<vertex> to <vertex>
```

or

```
horizontal=<vertex> to <vertex>
```

In addition to these two keys, there are corresponding primed options (`vertical'` and `horizontal'`) which adjust the overall orientation and then perform an additional flip.

Here's an example of a 4-point interaction in a λφ⁴ theory:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=i1 to f2, edges={scalar}] {
  {i1, i2} -- c [dot] -- {f1, f2},
};
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

One thing you'll notice is that `vertical` and `horizontal` can take *any (distinct) nodes*; the nodes need not be connected.

Comment: Unfortunately, for me, Overleaf complains: 
`Package pgfkey Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/edges', to which you passed 'scalar', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`